# How do I index f.items()?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, items

I could run a for loop as such:

```
for v in f.items():
```

BUT, it takes too much time. I know I want the second object in f.items(). How to I directly get the second object and save it?

Im not sure what the syntax is: e.g is it f.items(2), f.items()[2]? None of these work so I was wondering what does.

Comment: Assuming `f` is a dict, you cannot access dict items by numerical position. Looping and stopping at the second item is the only option. (You can hide the loop in a helper, or go through an iterator manually instead of with loop syntax, but there's no way to avoid the iteration machinery.)

Comment: If "access the nth item" is a common operation in your use case, a plain dict may not be the right choice of data structure.

Comment: You know you can `break` as soon as you have the second item, right?

Comment: You cannot index a dict items object. Or a dict for that matter.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can create a list and then index.

```
item = list(f.items())[1]
```

Lists are created often in python and this operation is relatively inexpensive. If your dictionary is large, you can create an iterator and take its second value.

```
i = iter(f.items())
next(i)
item = next(i)
```

But the dict would need to be rather large to make this the better option.

Comment: Creating a list may be cheap, but copying the entire contents of a dict into a new list just to get the second item is a waste of time. (Also, in my tests, depending on the test system, the iterator approach sometimes outcompeted the `list` approach even for a 2-element dict. On setups where it didn't, the breakeven point was still very low.)

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem!

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - "simpler is better". Using `next` is less obvious than creating a list (IMHO) and using it may well be a case of premature optimization. It may be a waste of time... but usually a trivially small waste of time, and that's why I suggested lists are the better option unless you expect fairly large dicts.

Comment: If you're concerned about readers not knowing what `next` does, wrap it in a function. Maybe use the `nth` recipe from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). This is not a sufficient justification to use an O(n) algorithm when there's an easy O(1) solution.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - wrrapping it in a function adds cost and complexity. With the list, its very easy to see what is going on.  Other solutions likely need a comment or doc string which is another hint that you've made the world complicated ... and for small dicts, needlessly so. If there was a "take_nth" function in itertools, then yeah, use what's there. Otherwise, just keep it obvious.

Comment: The OP *already said* looping over the dict was taking too long. What makes you think the input is small? Even without the explicit "it takes too much time", an O(n) approach would be unjustifiable, but when performance is specifically a concern like that?

Comment: Plus, if you're worried about people being inexperienced enough that they don't immediately see what's going on with the `iter`/`next` approach, you should also be worried about them not realizing that `list(f.items())` takes time proportional to the size of `f` (and you never mention the time complexity in your answer).

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - looping and using the list initializer written in C against the item iterator also written in C are very different things. Python does a good job with lists, it always has.

Answer (score 0):

If you want values(your 2nd objects) from f.items() you should use the below: -

```
for k,v in f.items()
```

Or if you want the 2nd item from f.items() you should use the below: -

```
f = {1:'A',2:'B',3:'C'}
for item in enumerate(f.items(),1):
    k,v = item
    if k == 2:
        print(v)
```

Do still want to extract 2nd value from 2nd item ?